# Adapting layout to changing screen orientation

Tags: responsive-design

I'm new to adaptive/responsive web development. I'm confused over how mobile devices handle the change of screen resolution when the orientation of the device is changed.

If I create two media queries - one for 320 (portrait) and one for 480 (landscape), the iphone only loads the 320 version, regardless of the orientation, adn just zooms to fill the screen.

Is there a way of delivering the new 480 styles when the iphone is loaded in landscape position, or when the iphone is tilted from portrait to landscape?

Answer (score 3):

First of all media queries have a property that you probably discovered

```
@media all and (orientation:portrait) { … }
@media all and (orientation:landscape) { … }
```

You could force render on the iPhone via

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
```

and then use some css to target landscape mode

```
@media screen and (min-width: 321px){
  //styles
}
```

Answer (score 1):

CSS media queries are a bit tricky with orientation form a device to another.
You still have a good js option:

```
window.addEventListener('orientationchange', changeOrientation, false);

function changeOrientation() {
if (orientation == 0 || orientation == 180) {
  //portraitMode
}
else {
  //LandscapeMode
}
```

Comment: This answer has fixed a different but related problem I had. Done purely in CSS, changing from full screen landscape to portrait (iPad 2) has a odd effect where the background doesn't stretch all the way to the bottom first time round. http://i44.tinypic.com/5a5bhj.jpg You have to rotate back to landscape then portrait again for it to work.